# NPM not finding entity pwsh

Tags: node.js, npm, enoent

I'm currently having a really annoying problem with npm.
I cant use npm at all at the moment.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn pwsh
npm ERR! path C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn pwsh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Things I tried:

- Reinstalled Node
- Reinstalled Powershell
- Installed another version of Node
- Tried in different projects
- Set executionpolicy to unrestricted

Comment: Have you tried to (re-)install PowerShell? Maybe it got broken somehow.

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work but ty anyways